# How to format HTML interface name using string variable

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, string, dom-manipulation

As in description: I am trying to format an HTML interface name using string stored in a variable.
So far I tried this:

```
function enableInputFieldTabSupportByTagAndId(tagName, HTMLInterfaceName, textareaId, tabSize) {

// this returns "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'getCaretPosition' of undefined'"

  `HTML${HTMLInterfaceName}Element`.prototype.getCaretPosition = function () {
    //return the caret position of the input field
    return this.selectionStart;

// this returns "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'getCaretPosition' of undefined"

  $("HTML" + HTMLInterfaceName + "Element").prototype.getCaretPosition = function () {
    //return the caret position of the input field
    return this.selectionStart;

// this is valid but only for textarea interface

  HTMLTextAreaElement.prototype.getCaretPosition = function () {
    //return the caret position of the input field
    return this.selectionStart;
  };
```

Later on this work fine with third option, but only for textarea tag:

```
// this returns "Uncaught TypeError: inputField.getCaretPosition is not a function
    at HTMLInputElement.inputField.onkeydown" for input tag

var inputField = document.getElementsByTagName(tagName)[textareaId];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to access the element from the `window` using bracket notation, instead of wrapping the string as a jQuery object.

```
window["HTML" + HTMLInterfaceName + "Element"].prototype.getCaretPosition = function(){
  //...
}
```